# Cannot update alternate key entity framework core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework 7 or core 1.0 for my new project. In the products table, **ProductName** column is set as an alternate key (unique constraint). The problem is that I'm unable to update this column in the database. The code for edit actions is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(ProductViewModel product, int id, IFormFile ProductImage)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Product = _products.Find(x => x.ProductID == id).Single();
            string tempName = Product.ProductName; //for deleting directory if name has been changed.
            Product = _mapper.Map<Product>(product);

            //code to replace image file if new file has been uploaded OR
            //delete / change directory if the product name has been changed
            //goes here

            //Insert id again after mapping 
            Product.ProductID = id;
            ProductImage image = _images.Find(m => m.ProductID == id).Single();
            image.Hash = FileName;
            image.Product = Product;
            image.Extension = FileExtension;
            image.ProductID = Product.ProductID;
            _products.Update(Product);
            _images.Update(image);
            if (_products.SaveAll() && _images.SaveAll())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    product.Categories = _categories.GetAll().ToList();
    return View(product);
}
```

I've debugged through all of this and everything is working fine, all other properties are being updated in the database, the **ProductName** is being updated in memory objects (not the database), the files / folders are being replaced, even the **images** database table is being updated, but when the product name is changed the return statement inside the **SaveAll()** if statement isn't executed nor is this particular column in database being updated. Please help!

Comment: Im sure you can simplify your code. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Done

Comment: Still isnt clear to me where is the error. Can you be  more specific, do you get any error? Also can you try `db.SaveChanges();`  instead `_products.Update(Product);`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza mate there is no error. It just doesn't update the column and skips the redirect statement inside the `saveall` if and returns the same edit form. And regarding `db.SaveChanges();`, I'm using repository pattern with `SaveAll()` method abstracting `db.SaveChanges();`. Hope this helps.

Comment: So update some columns and other doesnt? In that case you should check your class definition to see if some has the ReadOnly Property

Comment: sadly no it ain't that case. :-( @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Any help?

Comment: I cant guess what is wrong. Split your problematic table in multiple tables. One with an int, second with int and char and so on until you find what is the field causing your problem.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza nothing helps :-(

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Found the answer. Thank you and sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok I've found the answer through Entity Framework Core's Github. Here's the answer:

EF Core currently does not support changing the value of alternate keys. We do have [#4073](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4073) tracking removing this restriction though.

BTW it only needs to be an alternate key if you want it to be used as the target key of a relationship. If you just want a unique index, then use the  HasIndex()  method, rather than  AlternateKey() . Unique index values can be changed.

Source:
[Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4914)

Comment: Good find. I spent way to long on figuring that out.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the column setted as an alternate key.

If you just want a unique index in your table you can use `HasIndex` with `IsUnique`, for example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.ProductName)
        .IsUnique();
}
```

> Indexes are a common concept across many data stores. While their
>   implementation in the data store may vary, they are used to make
>   lookups based on a column (or set of columns) more efficient. By
>   convention, an index is created in each property (or set of
>   properties) that are used as a foreign key.

Read more about [EF Core Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes)